# Finding eigenvalues for a vectorspace such that the matrixrepresentation is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Problem:** Let $T$ be a linear operator on the vectorspace $V = M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $T\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} d & b \\ c & a \end{pmatrix}$. Find the eigenvalues of $T$ and an ordered basis $\beta$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ is a diagonal matrix.

**Attempt at a solution:** I don't really know how to begin, so I just picked the standard ordered basis for  $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$. Putting each of these basisvectors in the operator got me the same vectors, except in different order (elements on the diagonal get interchanged). But how do I set up $[T]_{\beta}$ now?

There was a similar problem, but with $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T(a,b) = (-2a +3b, -10a +9b)$. Here I found the solution by using the standard ordered basis, putting them in the operator, and then setting up the matrixrepresentation of that output. After that I just found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and when I used the operator on the eigenvectors, I got the desired diagonal matrix.

But how can I do this in the problem above, where I'm given matrices?

Comment: Hint: Find a basis for $M_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R})$, and write each matrix in that basis. Then, you can solve the problem as in $\Bbb{R}^4$.

Comment: You mean I have to express the transformed matrices as a linear combination of the basisvectors, and then setup a $4 \times 4$-matrix from that? But when I have to find the eigenvalues, I have to compute the determinant of a $4 \times 4$-matrix then, or not?

Comment: Yes, if you do the calculations you will find the eingevalue equal 1,1,1,-1.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to work in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so, in this case, we have that:

$$T(a, b, c, d) = (d, b, c, a)$$

Now, in the standard basis,

$$T(e_1) = e_4$$
$$T(e_2) = e_2$$
$$T(e_3) = e_3$$
$$T(e_4) = e_1$$

Hence, we have just discovered that $e_2$ and $e_3$ are eigenvectors of eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$. More importantly, this means that

$$[T]_{E_4} = \begin{pmatrix} 0  & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, the characteristic polynomial is

$$det(T-\lambda I) = (\lambda - 1)^3 (\lambda + 1)$$

Doing as you did before should yield that $(-1, 0, 0, 1)$ is the only eigenvector of eigenvalue -1, and $(1, 0, 0, 1)$ is the eigenvector of eigenvalue 1 that we were lacking.

Hence, the basis is

$$\beta = \{(-1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0)\}$$

Comment: Did you really calculate the determinant of that $4 \times 4$-matrix or did you use some trick? I calculated that determinant and eventually I got a polyonomial of degree $2$, with discrimant zero, so I only got one eigenvalue. How did you solve it?

Comment: Well, by hand. I just put it into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%2C+0%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%7D%7D) and it spits out the same thing, so yeah.